# Using index, match + search with array formula for header row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have working formula if I use this formula in every row. But my table is connected to google forms, so when new data is generated my formula shifts down as new row is created and doesn't work. So I need to put array formula to the header row, so that every time new row created, the array formula generates desired result.

```
=arrayformula(INDEX($E$2:$E$13,MATCH(1,SEARCH($E$2:$E$13,A2),-1))))
```

Not working formula for header array row:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(
              ifs(row(C:C)=1,"Header_array_formula",
                  isblank(A:A),"",
                  len(A:A)>0,INDEX($E$2:$E$13,MATCH(1,SEARCH($E$2:$E$13,A:A),-1))),""))
```

[image: Sample]

Here is link to my sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q5fkhk3o9SQTt4ye37vfVEjzQ6zREbu-8a-xMsA7wYs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That is not Excel.  It is google sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Header_array_formula";PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:index(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),"(?i)"&JOIN("|",E2:index(E:E,COUNTA(E:E)))))})
```

Use REGEX+JOIN to create a regex  with or operator `|`  joining all the criteria `E:E`.

Or with a simple modification to your formula: Just add `BYROW`:

```
={"Header";BYROW(A2:Index(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(r, INDEX($E$2:$E$13,MATCH(1,SEARCH($E$2:$E$13,r),-1))))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on-

```
={"Header_array_formula";BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,PROPER(FILTER(FLATTEN(SPLIT(x," ")),ISNUMBER(MATCH(FLATTEN(SPLIT(x," ")),E2:E13,0)))))))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
={"Header_array_formula"; 
 INDEX(PROPER(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A10, "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, E2:E)))))}
```

[image]